# OpenGL ES SensorManager particle position update

Tags: android, opengl-es, orientation, sprite, sensors

I am developing a sprite experiment that involves moving set of balls around the screen caused by change in orientation. But when I render (create and position) the particles in my `Renderer` class, how do I update their movements considering `SensorManager` is implemented in my `Activity` class. Following is the code. It may be long but I have curtailed as much redundancies to make you understand it.

Since this tends to be long, please ask me to clarify the bit you have trouble understanding and I'll address them through edit.

```
public class MyGLCubeTouchActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener  {

   private GLSurfaceView myTouchSurface;
   private SensorManager sm;
   public float xPosition, xAcceleration,xVelocity = 0.0f;
   public float yPosition, yAcceleration,yVelocity = 0.0f;
   public float xmax,ymax;
   public float frameTime = 0.666f;
   private List<MyGLBall> ball;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       myTouchSurface=new TouchSurfaceView(this);
       setContentView(myTouchSurface);
       sm=(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

     getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    sm=(SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    if(sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).size()!=0){

       Sensor s=sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
       sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);   
      }

    if(sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION).size()!=0){

     Sensor s=sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION).get(0);
     sm.registerListener(this, s, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

      }

     myTouchSurface.requestFocus();
     myTouchSurface.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
     xmax = (float)display.getWidth() - 50;
     ymax = (float)display.getHeight() - 50;

     ball=new ArrayList<MyGLBall>(36);
     for(int i=0;i<=35;i++){
     ball.add(new MyGLBall());
      } 
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    myTouchSurface.onPause();
    //sm.unregisterListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    myTouchSurface.onResume();
    // Register this class as a listener for the accelerometer sensor
    sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    // ...and the orientation sensor
     sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      if (arg0.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
        //Set sensor values as acceleration

        yAcceleration = arg0.values[1]; 
        xAcceleration = arg0.values[2];
        updateBall();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onsSensorChanged executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     }


}


    private void updateBall() {
    //Calculate new speed
    float xSpeed = xVelocity + (xAcceleration * frameTime);
    float ySpeed = yVelocity + (yAcceleration * frameTime);

    //Calc distance travelled in that time
    float xS = ((xVelocity + xSpeed)/2)*frameTime;
    float yS = ((yVelocity + ySpeed)/2)*frameTime;

    //Add to position negative due to sensor 
    //readings being opposite to what we want!
    xPosition -= xS; 
    yPosition -= yS;

    if (xPosition > xmax) {
        xPosition = xmax;
    } else if (xPosition < 0) {
        xPosition = 0;
    }
    if (yPosition > ymax) { 
        yPosition = ymax;
    } else if (yPosition < 0) {
        yPosition = 0;
    }
    }

     public class TouchSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView  {

    private MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public TouchSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            mRenderer=new MyGLRenderer();
            setRenderer(mRenderer);
            setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

    }

     class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

        private Random r;
        private MyGLCube mCube;
        public float mAngleX;
        public float mAngleY; 

        public MyGLRenderer(){
            r=new Random(); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
             gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);   

             gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
             gl.glLoadIdentity();
             gl.glClientActiveTexture(DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);


            for(int i=0;i<=35;i++){

             float randX=(float)((r.nextFloat()) *(1.0f - (-1.0f)) + (-1.0f));
             float randY=(float)((r.nextFloat()) *(1.0f - (-1.0f)) + (-1.0f));
                gl.glPushMatrix();
                     gl.glTranslatef(randX, randY, -3.0f);
                     gl.glScalef(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
                     gl.glColor4f(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1);
                     gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);


                     ball.get(i).draw(gl);
                gl.glPopMatrix();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            float ratio=(float) width/height;
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            //gl.glOrthof(-2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 25);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
            gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
            gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


       }            
     }

    }       
}
```

Here's the implementation for **MyGLBall**

```
       public class MyGLBall {

private final float degToRad=(float) (3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0);  
private int points=360;
private float vertices[]={0.0f,0.0f,0.0f}, colorVals[]={0.2f,0.6f,0.3f,1.0f};
private FloatBuffer vertBuff, colorBuff, alBuff, dlBuff, slBuff, lPosBuff, lDirecBuff;
private float[] al = {0.03f, 0.07f, 0.03f, 1.0f}, dl={0.3f, 0.8f, 0.2f, 1.0f}, sl={0.6f, 0.4f, 0.8f, 1.0f}; 
float shineness = 0.4f;
float[] lPosition = {0.5f, 0.8f, 0.3f, 0.4f};
float[] lDirection = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f};

//centre of circle

public MyGLBall(){

    vertices=new float[(points+1)*3];
    colorVals=new float[(points+1)*4];
    for(int i=3;i<(points+1)*3;i+=3){
      double rad=(i*360/points*3)*(3.14/180);
      vertices[i]=(float)Math.cos(rad);
      vertices[i+1]=(float) Math.sin(rad);
      vertices[i+2]=0;    
    }

    for(int i=4;i<(points+1)*4;i+=4){
      float colorVal=r.nextFloat();
      colorVals[i]=colorVal;
      colorVals[i+1]=colorVal;
      colorVals[i+2]=colorVal;
      colorVals[i+3]=1;
    } 

      ByteBuffer bBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);    
      bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      vertBuff=bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      vertBuff.put(vertices);
      vertBuff.position(0);

      ByteBuffer bColorBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colorVals.length*4);
      bColorBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      colorBuff=bColorBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      colorBuff.put(colorVals);
      colorBuff.position(0);

      ByteBuffer bAlBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(al.length*4);
      bAlBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      alBuff=bAlBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      alBuff.put(al);
      alBuff.position(0);

      ByteBuffer bDlBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(dl.length*4);
      bDlBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      dlBuff=bDlBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      dlBuff.put(dl);
      dlBuff.position(0);

      ByteBuffer bSlBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(sl.length*4);
      bSlBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      slBuff=bSlBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      slBuff.put(sl);
      slBuff.position(0);

      ByteBuffer bLPosBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lPosition.length*4);
      bLPosBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
      lPosBuff=bLPosBuff.asFloatBuffer();
      lPosBuff.put(lPosition);
      lPosBuff.position(0);

} 

public void draw(GL10 gl){

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);     
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
//  gl.glScalef(size, size, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

 }  

  }
```

Comment: Please add the implementation of `MyGLBall`. Does it contain its position, velocity, and acceleration?

Comment: @StefanHanke updated my answer. And no, I don't. Is that an issue?

Comment: This depends on what you want to achieve ;) When the user tilts the device, the balls shall move as if they were on top of the device?

Comment: which side the phone is tilted towards the balls go that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is kind of a code review. I hope this gets you started.

1. The ball's are physical objects (sort of), and have their own position, velocity, and acceleration. This state must be updated on a sensor change. This is a bit fiddling with the values. Don't forget to ask the `GLSurfaceView` to [redraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#requestRender%28%29). The draw logic then needs to use the position to move the ball to the correct position.
2. I haven't looked into sensor calibration at all, implemented a simple calibration that measures the sensor output the first five seconds and then setting a base value. The orientation sensor is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ORIENTATION).
3. Consider setting some random values for the initial state of the balls.
4. Consider throwing out code that is just clutter. For example, you have any textures here?